# unlock first house in the village

Tags: candy-box-2

How do you get into the first house in the village it says its locked, also what is in that house?

I need to get into the one on the left

[image: house]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no, you can't unlock the house. But maybe aniwey will make that house "openable" in further updates